# Classification of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am trying to classify rings of order 10. I believe the only possible ring is $\mathbb{Z_{10}}$. Thus I am trying to find a map from my ring $R$ to $\mathbb{Z_{10}}$. The most obvious map $f: R \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_{10}}$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(n)=[n]_{10}$. I was able to prove that it was a homomorphism and surjective. However, I am stuck at proving injectivity. Can anyone please give me some hints

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick: Thanks for pointing it out. I am just having trouble with one subpart of the question which I believe is not mentioned in the above link. I would just want to know whether my approach is correct and get some hints.

Comment: Note that for a mapping of one set of ten elements to another set of ten elements to be surjective (onto), it must also be injective (1-1) by finiteness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A surjection between two finite sets of the same size is injective, which finishes your proof. This has nothing to do with ring theory, it's simply a theorem for finite sets. (If your map satisfies $f(x) = f(y)$ for $x \neq y$, then $10 = |f(R)| < |R| = 10$.)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the additive part of the ring must be an abelian group.  What do you know about groups of order 10?

Comment: We know they are cyclic groups.